# Itinerary Optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization, maps

I am looking for a web-based solution to optimize a salesman's itinerary: the salesman has a list of destinations (~10), and is looking for the shortest way to visit them all.

Google Maps calculates an itinerary, but doesn't optimize it (it takes the destinations in the order they are entered).

Is there any other solution around?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Somebody should joke-post this to the "programming" Reddit :-)

Comment: Are you talking about theoretical scenarios where you already have all the map data? Or do you want to literally travel around and you're looking for the best route (so you don't have a map)?

Comment: I have a sample in F# if that's interesting to you.

Comment: thejh: I just know the locations - street address or longitude and latitude. Pointy: I don't get your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty decent: http://gebweb.net/optimap/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the optimap-library I've written a solution supporting groups and compare the price and a error code: http://www.chihoang.de/index.php?id=1373